# Upload a whole directory with using Python and ftplib

Tags: python, ftp

i try to upload a whole directory to a server using python and ftplib.

```
template_dir = '/Users/seb/projects/citats/static/templates/blanka/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(template_dir, topdown=True):
    relative = root[len(template_dir):].lstrip(os.sep)
    for d in dirs:
        ftp.mkd(os.path.join(relative, d))

    for f in files:
        ftp.cwd(relative)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + f, open(os.path.join(template_dir, relative, f), 'rb'))
        ftp.cwd('/')

ftp.quit()
```

This solution works fine but in my opinion it could be widely improved (especially the file loop).
Can you advice me ?

Comment: You don't seem to have a particular problem with your code, as you say your solution works fine. I suggest you move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could ask this on [codereview.se], but first you'll want to clarify what you're looking to improve.

Answer (score 1):

you did not close your files

```
for f in files:
    filePath = os.path.join(template_dir,relative,f)
    ftp.cwd(relative)
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as fileObj:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR '+f,fileObj)
    ftp.cwd('/')
```

for those who don't know, the 'with open(file_path,mode) as f:' syntax automatically closes files when the indent aligns back with 'with'